# firebase document some fields are showing as null when map and array exist in the document

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am having documents with array and map fields. When I try to get this in the data class some other fields are getting null.

for example - orderQty is getting as null.

[image: firebase order document]

[image: data class]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, I can see that the names of the fields in your `Orders` class are different than the names that exist in the database. In your class, the fields start with an upper-case letter, while in the database start with a lower-case letter. And this is not correct, the names must match. The simplest solution would be to change the names of the fields in the class. So a field called `OrderNo` should be changed to `orderNo`. See the lower-case `o`?

Alternatively, you can use an annotation like this:

```
@get:PropertyName("orderNo")
@set:PropertyName("orderNo")
var OrderNo: String? = null,
```

Comment: Yes. Got it. Alex. i stuck in this problem since last 5 days. Now its resolved. Thanks a lot Alex. While posting this issue i have expected your solution only. And you have done it. I have learned maximum programming from your tutorials only. Thank you once again. Kudos to you.

Comment: You're very welcome, Sabir.